# How to add a "Clear Button" into paper-dropdown-menu?

Tags: html, web, polymer, web-component

In a paper-input I have a "Clear Button":

```
 <paper-input
          id="myinput" maxlength="10" char-counter label="myinput"
          always-float-label required>
  <paper-icon-button suffix 
         onclick="clearInput('InputClientes')" 
         icon="clear" 
         class="iconClear" 
         alt="clear" 
        title="clear">
  </paper-icon-button>
 </paper-input>
```

It is possible to add a similar button (Clear Button) to a paper-dropdown-menu to clear the selection?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you use a `paper-dropdown-button` with a `paper-listbox` inside, you can call its `selected` property to `null` to clear the current value.

**2.** Add a button that will call this method and style it with a `position:relative` CSS rule to position it at the right place.

**3.** Listen for the `iron-select` event to show the [close] button when an item is selected in the list.

```
<paper-dropdown-menu id=PDM label="Your favourite pastry">
    <paper-listbox id=PL  class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>Croissant</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Donut</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Financier</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Madeleine</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
<paper-icon-button id=CloseBtn icon="clear" onclick="clearInput()" hidden ></paper-icon-button>

<script>
    function clearInput() {
        PL.selected = null
        CloseBtn.hidden = true 
    }
    PDM.addEventListener( 'iron-select', function ( ev ) {
        CloseBtn.hidden = false 
    } )
</script>
```